# convert hash value into string in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a hash value and I want to convert it into string formate but I do not know how to do that.

Here is the hash value

```
7616db6c232292d2e56a2de9da49ea810d5bb80d53c10e7b07d9521dc88b3177
```

Comment: By "convert it into string format" do you mean recover the original string from it, as the current answers suggest, or just to turn `7616db6.....` into a string so that you could, for instance, output it?

Comment: Where did you get that hash value?  Show us the lines that printed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing technique is a one way algorithm. So that is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A hash is a one-way function. Plus, two strings could theoretically generate the same hash.

**BUT**. If you had a large enough, pre-computed list of as many hashes as you could generate for each unique string, you could *potentially* convert your hash back into a string. Although it would require thousands of GB in entries and a *lot* of time to compute each and every hash. So it practically isn't possible.